# jquery getting data from :has selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have four links on the page that looks like this

```
<ul class="groups-list">
<li class="group-link active" data-group="australia" data-day="2015-03-24"><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
<li class="group-link" data-group="united-kingdom" data-day="2015-03-24"><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
<li class="group-link" data-group="south-africa" data-day="2015-03-24"><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the the group data attribute with :has jquery selector like this

```
var load_group = $( ".groups-list:has(active)" ).data('group');
        console.log(load_group);
```

That gives undefined? I also tried it like this

```
var load_group = $( ".group-link:has(active)" ).data('group');
```

Same result, how can I get a data attribute of an element that has a specific class.

P.S https://jsfiddle.net/rx27qv4L/

Comment: **Hint:** `$(".groups-list:has(active)")` returns an object.  It is `.data('group')` that appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query for the class?

```
var load_group = $(".groups-list .active").data('group');
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to retrieve the `data-group` attribute of the element `.groups-list` that contains an element of type `active`. The element `.groups-list` doesn't have a `data-group` attribute, you need to select the child element with class `.active`.

Therefore the selector should be `$(".groups-list:has(.active) .group-link.active")`, which will select the element `.groups-list` that contains an `.active` descendant element. From there, it will select the `.group-link` element with class `.active`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ed4u4Lc3/)

```
var load_group = $(".groups-list:has(.active) .group-link.active").data('group');
```

You really don't need `:has` in this case, though:

```
var load_group = $(".groups-list .group-link.active").data('group');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

`var load_group = $(".groups-list li.active").data('group');
alert(load_group);`